# Emulate mouse wheel scroll with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse-wheel

Some programs (e.g. ms html help viewer) have zoom-in features that only seem to work when you mouse wheel scroll.

Is there a way to emulate mouse wheel scroll using the keyboard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's possible with [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com).

Try this script for instance: [**Using Keyboard Numpad as a Mouse**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/NumpadMouse.htm). It uses the Numeric Pad to emulate a mouse. When on, NumPad+ and Numpad- emulates the mouse wheel.

Comment: Do you know of a Linux solution?

Answer (score 3):

[SerioSoft MKey](http://web.archive.org/web/20190622174130/http://www.seriosoft.org/en/download.php) does the job quite well.

This is much easier than making AutoHotKey scripts. TIP: If scroll doesn't work after making "scroll hotkey" try to change default scroll speed setting from "1" to "2".

---

You can also take a look at: [AtnSoft Key Manager](https://atnsoft.com/keymanager)

Comment: the link shows a blank white page to me. just me?

Comment: That web site seems defunct :( Maybe the program has been uploaded on a third-party server somewhere.

Comment: per [Dagan Devenic](https://superuser.com/users/1136917/dagan-danevic): I don't have enough rep to comment on drabsv's answer, but you can still grab this from the wayback machine here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20190622174130/http://www.seriosoft.org/en/download.php

Answer (score 1):

This is not a generic answer to your question, but notice that some softwares such as Visual Studio Code allow the documents to be scrolled using a key combination as well, so you might want to check out the configuration of the software you're using the most for such shortcut key settings. In my case, it's  <kbd>Ctrl + Up/Down</kbd>  in VSCode by default to scroll down as much as one line, and  <kbd>Alt + PageDown/PageUp</kbd>  to scroll down the whole page a few more lines(more than one line) down and up. I've personally remapped the latter to  <kbd>Alt + z/x</kbd>  since it's easier for my hand.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows): Check out [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), it can remap the Mouse Wheel.

From [the docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> Mouse Wheel Hotkeys [Windows
> NT/2000/XP or later]
>
> Hotkeys that fire
> upon turning the mouse wheel are
> supported via the key names WheelDown
> and WheelUp. WheelLeft and WheelRight
> are also supported in v1.0.48+, but
> have no effect on operating systems
> older than Windows Vista.

Comment: this is the other way around: capturing when the real wheel is used on the mouse.

Comment: Good point, it was mostly just to show AHK is 'mouse wheel aware'. :)